# Remove whitespace/blank spaces in table columns XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

[image]

The link has a table in a PDF generated using Apache-FOP.

I am unable to remove the blank spaces/empty spaces in the table column headers and column values.

The PDF has limitation of 120 characters and thus unable to display all the text.

The application does supply the column width. But unsure how to use it in the xsl-fo file

Please suggest how to define widths of the table columns to hold only the text and without any blank/unused spaces.

Comment: Please suggest an answer

Comment: Have you tried to use whitspace handling as descriped in http://www.learn-xsl-fo-tutorial.com/Blocks-Inlines.cfm#h1.6

Answer (score 1):

Use `fo:table-column` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-column) and the `column-width` property to specify the width of each column.  For example:

```
<fo:table-column column-width="100pt" column-number="1" />
```

If you generate the `fo:table-column` in sequence, then you can omit the `column-number` property (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#column-number).

If you are using FOP, it still doesn't implement automatic table layout, so you probably also have to set the table width to be the sum of the column widths plus the border widths.